# Gnu Assembly (GAS) error with dc.b and String

Tags: assembly, constants, gnu

i'm facing new problem with this Gas operation:

```
dc.b  "MESSAGE"
```

this gaves me a Bad Expression error:

```
Error: Rest of line ignored. First ignored character is `M'.
```

I tried many escapes and any trick with no luck.

Usually i used string this way:

```
.ascii "MESSAGE"
```

But this can't be used for assigning addresses as:

```
dc.b #0,d1
```

Because if i try this:

```
.ascii  "MESSAGE",0xFF
```

i get the following result:

```
Error: Rest of line ignored. First ignored character is `0'.
```

so can't replace dc statement.

Thanks!

EDIT: I forget to mention this error at line 0:

```
myasmfile.s:0: Warning: end of file in comment; newline inserted
```

I can't figure out why this cames out either...

Comment: _"But this can't be used for assigning addresses as: `dc.b #0,d1`"_ Huh? I don't really understand what the problem is? Can you explain again why you can't use `.ascii` for your strings?

Comment: I've updated the question thread, hope it's more clear now, thanks 4 your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if i try this:

```
.ascii  "MESSAGE",0xFF
```

> i get the following result:
>
> Error: Rest of line ignored. First ignored character is `0'.

Do this instead:

```
.ascii "MESSAGE"
dc.b 0xFF
```

`0xFF` is kind of an unusual string terminator though. If you use the more standard zero-terminated strings you can use the `.asciz` directive which will add the terminator for you:

```
.asciz "MESSAGE"
```

To get the address of the string, just place a label ahead of it:

```
foo: .asciz "MESSAGE"
```

And then you can do:

```
move.l      #foo,a0
```